# upload multiple image files

Tags: php, file, upload

I am making a form which allows users to upload multiple files(Images). I have made a file array but the code does not seem to work. I have no errors but still the file is not transferred to the location i am sending it too.

```
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
                $listing_data = array(
                    'title'         => $_POST['title'],
                    'category'      => $_POST['category'],
                    'description'   => $_POST['description'],
                    'name'          => $_POST['name'],
                    'price'         => $_POST['price'],
                    'email'         => $_POST['email'],
                    'keywords'      => $_POST['keywords'],
                    'phone'         => $_POST['number'],
                );

                if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
                        $name_array = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                        $file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                        $allowed = array('jpg','png','gif', 'jpeg');
                        $file_extn = explode('.', $name_array);
                        $file_path ='images/listings/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . strtolower(end($file_extn));

                            if(in_array(strtolower(end($file_extn)), $allowed) === true){
                                upload_image($file_temp, $file_extn);
                              }
                            }     
                    add_listing($listing_data);
                    header('Location: addlisting.php?success');
                    exit();

            }elseif (empty($errors) === false){
                echo output_errors($errors);
            }

function upload_image($file_temp, $file_extn){
    $file_path ='images/listings/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . strtolower(end($file_extn));
    for($i = 0; $i < count($file_temp); $i++){
        move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
     }
}
```

`Photos:<br>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
            <input type="file" name="file[]">
            <input type="file" name="file[]">
            <input type="file" name="file[]">
            <input type="file" name="file[]">`

Comment: Should try to isolate your problem a bit more, at what point does it break?

Comment: Please, add your form code as well.

Comment: Heard of `<input type="file" multiple>`?

Comment: I tried multiple but it still dos not work. The file is not getting transferred from it temporary location probably.